# Why can't I Init attribute in Managed Bean constructor?

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb, managed-bean, postconstruct

I have a Managed Bean:

```
public class CategoriaManagedBean {
  @EJB
  private CategoriaBeanLocal categoriaBean;
  private Categoria categoria;
  private List<Categoria> menu;
}
```

In my constructor I try:

```
public CategoriaManagedBean() {
  menu = categoriaBean.findByIdCategoriaPadre(0);
}
```

But I get a error "Cannot create the instance of the class", why can't I initialize the attribute in the constructor?

I fix the problem with:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  menu = categoriaBean.findByIdCategoriaPadre(0);
}
```

But I want to know the reason and if I am doing well with @PostConstruct

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) is the correct approach.

EJBs are injected *after* the constructor is invoked on a ManagedBean.

That's why there is a [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation.

Here's the first line from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html):

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization.